# Moodle mobile ionic 1 app PDF files are not open in some devices

Tags: ionic-framework, moodle

Moodle mobile ionic 1 app PDF files are not open in some devices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeBta.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your devices don't have any app capable of opening PDF files